# component hierarchy and onChange functions in React

Tags: reactjs, onchange, hierarchy

I am trying to make a system to help standardize form inputs and validation for our app and I'm not sure how to handle change events properly.

I am setting up components in the following structure, Starting at the bottom and working up:

1. NumberInput: a managed `<input>` field that makes sure only numeric values and has settings to allow/disallow decimals, max/min values etc. This is like type="number" except I can make it behave the way I want. It is the initial source of all the onChange events. and controls which characters can be entered, etc.
2. YearInput. Invokes a NumberInput and automatically adds maxLength 4 and other specific things to it.
3. Form Field component. looks like `<YearinputField label="Birth Day" name="">`. Used to standardize error reporting, labels and form wrapper divs. Will have `<inputField` component and pass the actual inputs in `this.props.children`. Would need to get validation messages from children and from parent potentially (parent knows if field is invalid based on external logic, child knows if a year isn't valid for instance.
4. Form level component: knows business logic, handles updating state or making calls to store, etc. Needs to be able to respond to value changes in the inputs. I would like not to need to change much about how these components work. Right now they have a pattern where I call `onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'field-name')}` and it would be awesome to be able to keep those intact. I would like for whether I'm using a regular input, a YearInput, or NumberInput not to affect how this component works.

One thing that's catching me is if the `NumberInput` component knows its invalid, how does it tell the FieldInput to add the error class to its containing div? I think the parent passing in restrictions can be covered by either passing in a function or props like 'maximum', and 'minimum'.

The main thing though, is I'm not sure what passing down of business I have to set up for the parent component to fire an `onChange` and know the value of the input at the end of the change.

I want every component except the very top one to be 'dumb' and have no knowledge of any of the application architecture. Are there any patterns or examples I could use to help me figure this out?

Comment: Pass the `onChange` handler from the top-level component all the way down to where you need it. Ideally, only your store is aware of business logic.